# How do I make my character attack on the side of the character that I click the LMB on (Unity)?

Tags: unity, movement, combat

This is a top-down game, I guess I should also mention that the character is not centred on the screen and the attack should be in 4 different directions. The attack's direction should be based on which side of the character(up, down,  left, right) that you click on(this should also be universal on the screen, the only deciding factor should be the character and the mouse). I really have no clue where to start on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can not provide you with a copy&paste code snippet, because too many details depend on how exactly you set up your scene. So I can only give you a few pointers of what you have to do and what tools you might use to do these things.

What you need to do is:

1. Find the pixel-position of the mouse cursor on the screen.
2. Convert it to a position in world space
3. Calculate the directional vector between player position and cursor position in world space
4. Convert that vector into a more simple up-down-left-right vector
5. Use that directional vector for your projectiles

**Step 1** is very simple. The [`Input.mousePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) property gives you the screen coordinates of the mouse cursor.

**Step 2** depends on how you set up your camera. When your camera uses orthographic projection, your world is 2d and the camera is looking straight at it, then the z-coordinate does not matter. That means you can just use the [`Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) method. But when you are using a perspective camera, then it gets a bit more complicated, because the position in world-space depends on the distance between the camera and the object the player is pointing at. You need to perform a raycast from the camera through the mouse cursor. Thankfully, there is a handy utility method for calculating that ray: [`Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html). You can then feed that ray into [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) / [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) to find the point the cursor is pointing at. Or when your game mechanics takes place on a 2D plane, you can store its definition in a [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html) object and use the method [`plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) to find where the mouse-ray intersects that plane.

This, of course, all assumes that you have exactly one camera in your scene which is tagged as the "Main Camera". When this is not the case, then you of course need to specify which camera you want to use to translate its perspective to the game world. So you have to substitute `Camera.main` with the respective Camera component.

**Step 3** is again much more straight-forward:

```
Vector3 mouseDirection = (mouseCursorWorldPosition - player.transform.position).normalized
```

But now you got a vector which points in the exact direction. You said you only want up, down, left or right. So **step 4** would be to simplify that vector. This code snippet assumes that you set up your camera that x is the left-right axis and y the up-down axis. Again, there are other ways to do it, and if you did, you need to modify this accordingly.

```
Vector3 simpleShootingDirection = Vector3.zero;
if( Mathf.Abs(mouseDirection.y) > Mathf.Abs(mouseDirection.x)) {
    // we got a direction which is more up-down than left-right
    if(mouseDirection.y > 0) {
        simpleShootingDirection = Vector3.up;  
    } else {
        simpleShootingDirection = Vector3.down;
    }        
} else {
    // we got a direction which is more left-right than up-down
    if(mouseDirection.x > 0) {
        simpleShootingDirection = Vector3.right;  
    } else {
        simpleShootingDirection = Vector3.left;
    }
}
```

And in **step 5**, you just need to apply that shooting direction to the projectiles. Now there are again at least a dozen different ways to make a projectile move through the game world in Unity. About half of them start with rotating the projectile into the shooting direction. Which you can do by simply changing the `transform.forward` property:

```
projectile.transform.forward = shootingDirection;
```

About the other half involve move the object by a vector, either directly by changing its position or indirectly by applying a velocity of force. But in any case, you need a vector which multiplies the direction vector by the desired speed/acceleration/force of the projectile:

```
projectileVector = shootingDirection * projectileSpeed
```